# JavaScript access local json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, frontend, create-react-app

So I have a JSON file with mock data:

```html
{
  "name": "Harvey Specter",
  "location": "New York, USA",
  "picture": "",
  "likes": 121,
  "following": 723,
  "followers": 4433,
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "author": {
        "picture": "",
        "name": "Mike Ross"
      },
      "date": "",
      "body": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "author": {
        "picture": "",
        "name": "Rachel Zein"
      },
      "date": "",
      "body": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "author": {
        "picture": "",
        "name": "Louis Litt"
      },
      "date": "",
      "body": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I access it through javascript, and display the data in my React SPA?
Also, I would like to be able to change the data i.e. if I click the 'follow' button it increments followers in JSON.

Comment: You cannot load local files from disk without user interaction due to security reasons.

Comment: Then how do I go around that?

Comment: @AdamMarczyk, what technology do you use on server-side ?

Comment: Use a server. Or have the user select the file with a file input.

Comment: I do not use a server-side technology. This is my private project. I'm doing only front-end (from scratch)

Comment: You can't do this. You could mock the server-side, using any of the othe answers. But that way you can't persist any data. Or you could create a backend which allows you to do this as you asked.

Comment: @Pjetr, or can use `require` statement like in my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How do I access it through javascript, and display the data in my
>   React SPA?

You can make a `request` using `fetch` method in order to obtain the `data` from your file.

```
fetch("data.json")
    .then( (response) => {
      return response;
    }).then( (json) => {
      //do whatever
    });
```

or a `native` javascript request using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Asynchronous_request).

**If you want to read from `local` file.** use `require` statement.

```
var data = require('../../data.json');
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   //iterate data
```

You can display `data` using [render](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) function when `React` component is initialized.

> Also, I would like to be able to change the data i.e. if I click the
>   'follow' button it increments followers in JSON.

You can change the `array` object using `javascript`.

```
obj["followers"]=parseInt(obj["followers"])+1
```

and then save new object to `server-side` using `fetch` method.

Comment: I get an error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: @AdamMarczyk, where?

Comment: Instead of //do whatever comment I just put console.log(json)

Comment: That error says that your json is not in the correct format. Check if has valid syntax

Comment: I pasted the whole file here. Seems to me that it's fine

Comment: The use only `return response` like in my answer.

Comment: data.json should be one server-side file. If you need from local file use `require` like in my answer :) I updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153605/discussion-between-adam-marczyk-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll need a backend running, which does all tranfsforms on the data. 
There are a few very compelling reasons to do so.

First up, security. I wouldn't want a website to simply download files from my PC and even less having them save files to my drives without my explicit consent.

Secondly, if all your users had a local copy of this file, how would they now about any changes done to your file?

So you'll need a backend that maintains this data, preferably in a database. Because that's faster than any filebased data-storage.
Now you have options, but seeing you're doing a javascript based project, I'd advise you to use [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), which is javascript running on a server. 
For a database, if your data won't get more advanced, you could go for a simple [mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/), use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com) for ease of access. Or if you need more relational mapping you could choose to work with [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/).
And you could get all your transitions via a REST API, using for instance [loopback](https://loopback.io/). 
Or you could choose to do it realtime using websockets and use the library [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

But having a client-side application doing file transforms is out of the question.

Answer (score -1):

For development purposes you can just add the data as a regular variable like so:

```
var myData = JSON.parse( { "data" : "test test test" });
```

If you want to similate using an API you can then make a function returning a Promise like so:

```
function getData() { return Promise.resolve(myData) }
```

Then you can consume it almost like an (encapsulated) API call, like so:

```
getData()
  .then(resolvedData => console.log('my data is', resolvedData)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the object like so:

```
    let objRef = {name: "Harvey Specter"
             ,location: "New York, USA"
              ,picture: ""
                ,likes: 121
            ,following: 723
            ,followers: 4433
             ,comments:[{id: 0
                    ,author: {picture: ""
                                ,name: "Mike Ross" }
                      ,date: ""
                      ,body: "" }
                       ,{id: 1
                    ,author: {picture: ""
                                ,name: "Rachel Zein" }
                      ,date: ""
                      ,body: "" }
                       ,{id: 2
                    ,author: {picture: ""
                                ,name: "Louis Litt" }
                      ,date: ""
                      ,body: "" }]};
```

Some examples on how to reference:

```
    alert( objRef["name"] );

    alert( objRef["comments"][0]["author"]["name"] );
```