# How to Debug "P5.js + Node.js with Parse Json" file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, backend, p5.js

Everything is work great till I **"parse json file with node.js"**, I just want to **"load json file with node"** & **"the bubble image show up on html"**, how to debug so that the bubble show up?

***"Please use code for the answer"***

**Website for Learning>**

***The Coding Train***

**6.2: Classes in JavaScript with ES6 - p5.js Tutorial**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-HGdc8L-7w

**10.2: What is JSON? Part I - p5.js Tutorial**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NFkzw6oFtQ

**8.5: Saving Data to JSON File with Node.js - Programming with Text**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iZiqQZBQJY

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="infoJSON6.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**infoJSON6.js**

```js
//P5.js
//bubble = {
//    "x": 300,
//    "y": 200
//}

//P5.js + json
function preload() {
bubble = loadJSON("Data4.json");
}

//P5.js + Node.js with parse json
//var fs = require('fs');
//var data = fs.readFileSync('Data4.json');
//var bubble = JSON.parse(data);
//console.log(bubble);


    //Test Terminal
  /*
  node infoJSON6.js
  */


//P5.js + node without parse json
//  var fs = require('fs');
//var bubble = fs.readFileSync('Data4.json');
//console.log(bubble);




function setup() {
createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
background(0);
moveBy();
display();
}

function display() {
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(4);
    noFill();
    ellipse(bubble.x, bubble.y, 24, 24);
}

function move() {
    bubble.x = bubble.x + random(-5, 5);
    bubble.y = bubble.y + random(-5, 5);
}
```

**Data4.json**

```
{
"x": 300,
"y": 200 }
```

Comment: If you have an index.html, this most likely is not nodejs.

Comment: ?? I don't get what you mean? I just want to load or read the json file and fs.writefilesync, but before I can fs.writefilesync, I need to read the file first using fs.readFileSync, The Coding Train youtube work and I just use "node infoJSON6.js" in terminal and it work just fine, but the "bubble" did not show up, so I'm asking you how to "debug fs.readFileSync so that the bubble show up"

Comment: Node.js and the fs library can only be used on the backend. You have an index.html file, that of is used in the frontend. To load the JSON in the frontend, you can use fetch (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034867/12359120)

Comment: @NetLordOfData You've  asked a couple of questions that seem to be confusing the front-end and back-end. The front end (index.html) basically doesn't have any access to the file system. Node.js code needs to run on a server (localhost for development), and has no access to HTML, p5.js or events. `fs` only runs on a server. What's the problem with starting a localhost server with, say, `python3 -m http.server` and calling `loadJSON`, exactly? That's the normal way to load data in a front-end p5 sketch. You probably don't need `fs` or node here.

Comment: LOL I'm the one with the most confusing here, so here are the question with basic info: I just want to make the image appear from the html using "json file"(read) without using the "p5.js loadjson" and then "add some function to file"(write new data), do I use "fetch then use post", or "fs node.js", or do I use "python3 http.server" like you said. This time please add code to the answer or explain clearly step by step what to do first?