# How to "p5.js loadJson"(read json) in html file without http request and write fs to json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, debugging, p5.js

***How Do i debug this in order for me to read and write in json file to html without http request?***

I have already got the answer from my **previous question project** ***"How to use push() into array json file when "mouse click"?"*** but now I can't even load/read file from json to html by using my **p5.js loadjson project**, do i missing something? or do I doing it wrong by arrange my code in the right order?

this is my **previous answer project>**
[How to use push() into array json file when "mouse click"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719094/how-to-use-push-into-array-json-file-when-mouse-click)

my project use for **p5.js loadjson**>
[How to Debug "P5.js + Node.js with Parse Json" file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032142/how-to-debug-p5-js-node-js-with-parse-json-file)

**//my code>**

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch8.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**sketch8.js**

```js
function preload() {
    winston = loadJSON("Data2.json");
    }

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
  }
  
  function draw() {
   
//JSON parse & fs read Node.js
//    var fs = require('fs');
//    var data = fs.readFileSync('Data2.json');
//    var winston = JSON.parse(data);
//    console.log(winston);
  
    //Test Terminal
  /*
  node sketch7.js
  */
  

  
  
  {
      if (mouseIsPressed) {
          winston.xPositions.push(mouseX);
      } else {
          var data = JSON.stringify(winston, null, 2);
          fs.writeFileSync('Data2.json', data, finished);

          function finished(err) {
            console.log('all set.');
          }
      }
      



      stroke(64, 117, 207);
      fill(196, 33, 255);
      for (var i = 0; i < winston.xPositions.length; i++) { 
          line(winston.xPositions[i], 120, 194, 285);
          ellipse(winston.xPositions[i], 104, 32, 46);
      }
  }
  
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  textSize(16);
  text("Winston likes " + winston.likes[0] + " and " +  winston.likes[1], 10, 90);
  
  };//<
```

**Data2.json**

```js
{
    "likes": ["programming", "being programmed"],
    "xPositions": [100, 200]
}
```

**//<my code**

***After remove the else statement***

if I remove the else statement then I can read json file, but that will remove reason to write, I want to **"read and write" to json file to html**

```js
      if (mouseIsPressed) {
          winston.xPositions.push(mouseX);
      } /*else {
          var data = JSON.stringify(winston, null, 2);
          fs.writeFileSync('Data2.json', data, finished);

          function finished(err) {
            console.log('all set.');
          }
      }
      */ //<else write data to json
```

The reason i use node without http request cause of this code that I use>

***//node code>***

**app.js**

```js
//Create New File 2>>

var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    fs.writeFile('writeMeMe22.txt', data, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log('error', err);
      });
});

//Terminal
//node app
```

**readMe.txt**

```js
ya here???
```

***//<node code***

as you can see when i use **terminal** and type **node app** or **node app.js**, It create a new file when read file AKA **read and write with node**, the **new file** can also be **json** file as well, like **writeMeMe22.txt** > **writeMeMe22.json**

***//new file>***

**writeMeMe22.txt**

```js
ya here???
```

***//<new file***

Answer (score 1):

Since `sketch8.js` is running in a web browser you are not going to be able to use `fs.writeFileSync()` which is a Node.js function intended for use on the server side. Instead you will want to use [saveJSON()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveJSON) to initiate a file download.

Comment: thank for clarify the question, so node.js use with http and loadJSON use with saveJSON which I hadn't download the http yet cause of how complex using terminal are